# How would I read n lines where n is the first line in a file using Python?

Tags: python, io

I need to read in a file of sets of coordinates using Python. The first line will have a number, *n*, which is the number of coordinate sets that need to be read. Following the first line will be *n* lines, where each line contains a single coordinate pair.

Example (in this case, n =4):

```
n
(x,y)
(x,y)
(x,y)
(x,y)
```

**The catch is that there will be multiple sections in the file.** So the first n might be 10, with 10 sets of coordinates, and the next n might be 20, with 20 sets of coordinates following it.

As of right now I'm just reading the sections of coordinates in separately, but I would like it if I could any number of sections of coordinates in the file I'm reading in.

Comment: What have you tried? I think you can just restart after you read `n` number of lines, to read next `n` number of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to open a file for reading, [`readline()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline) to read file content line by line, and [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert from a string to an integer.

Here's an example implementation using these parts:

```
def read_coords(file_handle):
    try:
        nrecords = int(file_handle.readline())
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return [file_handle.readline() for i in range(nrecords)]

coord_sets = []
with open("some.txt") as f:
   coords = read_coords(f)
   while coords != False:
       coord_sets.append(coords)
       coords = read_coords(f)

print "coord_sets =",coord_sets
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into using generators. You could read the first line via the generator and then it will tell how many lines to yield, until the next read:

```
def gen_coord(a_file):
    num = 0
    for line in a_file:
        if num == 0:
            num = int(line)
        else:
            num -= 1
            yield line

source = open("somefile")
coords = gen_coord(source)
for coord in coords:
    print (coord)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are currently reading in different files with the leading n value followed by the n-number of coordinates. But, you want to do this with a single file.

What you could do is create a nested list, and append a list of coords to a main list, based off of your formatting.

```
coord_list = []
myfile = open('coords.txt','r')
while 1:
    coord_count = myfile.readline().replace('\n','')
    if not coord_count:
        break
    coord_list.append([myfile.readline().replace('\n','') for i in range(int(coord_count))])

print coord_list
```

- Note: that you may still have to convert these '(x,y)'s

Comment: Do you have a skype or email I could reach you at? I'd like to speak more about this approach.

Comment: you can shoot me an email at rgriffin122@hotmail.com. Just let me know what you want to know. Also, you can send me a message in this chat room:
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python